# Dynamically passing value to sms api in php?

Tags: php

This is my sms url

```
"https://example.com/api/sendhttp.php?authkey=#############&mobiles=".$mobile."&message=".urlencode($rem)."&sender=abcdef&route=#"
```

Here is my Code

```
<?php
    session_start(); 

    $mobile=98994564564;
    $rem="Hi";

    $url=$_SESSION['smsurl'];
    echo $url;
?>
```

What I am trying to do here is I am calling this url through session variable. But when I am displaying the url, it is not getting value of `$mobile` and `$rem`.

It should display

```
"https://example.com/api/sendhttp.php?authkey=#############&mobiles=8994564564"&message=".urlencode("Hi")."&sender=abcdef&route=#"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, `$_SESSION['smsurl']` does not contain the actual variables like `$mobile` or `$rem`, instead it contains the value of those variables. So you can't simply do `$mobile=ABC; $rem="XYZ"; $url=$_SESSION['smsurl'];` to change the query part of the URL.

The solution is,

- Parse the URL
- Change the query part of the URL
- Reconstruct the URL again

So your code should be like this,

```
<?php
    session_start(); 

    $mobile=98994564564;
    $rem="Hi";

    $urlArray = parse_url($_SESSION['smsurl']);
    parse_str($urlArray['query'], $qStringArray);
    $qStringArray['mobiles'] = $mobile;
    $qStringArray['message'] = urlencode($rem);
    $qString = http_build_query($qStringArray);

    $apiUrl = $urlArray['scheme'] . '://' . $urlArray['host'] . $urlArray['path'] . '?' . $qString;

    // Display the final URL
    echo $apiUrl;
?>
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer mate.I am new to php so didn't know a lot about this.Can you do me a favour? Can you please provide me the final url in this form                                           "https://example.com/api/sendhttp.php?authkey=#############&mobiles=8994564564"&message=".urlencode("Hi")."&sender=abcdef&route=#"

Comment: @SagarSharma `$apiUrl` is the final/desired URL you would get at the end. As I mentioned in the answer, do `echo $apiUrl;` to see the final URL.

Comment: I just did Sir!...i am getting this in echo                                                               ://?mobiles=98994564564&message=Hi

Comment: @SagarSharma Paste the actual URL you're getting and the expected one on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/index.php), and give me it's link here. Also, paste the content of `var_dump($urlArray);` there as well.

Comment: Okay Sir! Thanks for the Help! Much Appreciated

Comment: I was able to get the desired output...had to make some changes in the session variable.Thanks a ton sir..will let you know if i face any further problem +rep

Comment: @SagarSharma You're welcome! Glad I could help. :-) Please *accept* the answer if it resolved your issue. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)